# How to convert local date (without time) in UTC DateTime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, datetime-format

I am trying to convert the local date (without time) in UTC Date and pass it to server. Suppose I have a local date selected from Calendar which is `01-Jun-2021` and when converted to Date its `Tue Jun 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530`.

My requirement is that, it should be converted to `Mon May 31 2021 18:30:00 GMT+0530` and when sent to the server it should be `Mon May 31 2021 18:30:00` only. I tried do that with below code and it give me the desired result. However when it is sent to the server its like `5/31/2021 1:00:00 PM` in C#. My local develop machine is in IST Zone.

```
export const dateToUTC = (date: Date): Date => {
  let _date = new Date(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours(),
    date.getUTCMinutes(),
    date.getUTCSeconds(),
    date.getUTCMilliseconds()
  );
  return _date;
};
```

Can anyone please help me this query? I think the main issue is `GMT+0530` which is being passed to server. I can do some tweaks and paly with the offset value but it might not work always.

Comment: For now I have tweaked it with sending the datetime in string format to server and it works fine. May be if we can have some better way of doing it..

Comment: Can you tell what does this date and time represent on the server? Also, I would suggest you to pass the dates in ISO8601 format. There can be multiple representations of date, so use a standard format which can be understood by both client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case I would suggest using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.
The code would look like this:

```
// Moment wrapper object
var m = moment.parseZone('2021-06-01T00:00:00+05:30').utc();
// Default format
console.log(m.format()); // "2021-05-31T18:30:00Z"
// Your string for the server
console.log(m.format("ddd MMMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")); // Mon May 31 2021 18:30:00
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5kamxjL/)

Indeed there is some tweaking underneath, but at least you can rely on it.

Comment: Thank you @antanta it helped me, I did a minor tweak to format `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss` and on server side it was converted to DateTime data type.